# Is there a python command to force run a program whilst terminal is hanging?

Tags: python

I have a program which hangs the terminal when run. I want to force run the another program whilst the terminal is still hanging. I have tried `os.startfile()` command but doesn't work. Is there any python command to force run another file whilst the terminal is hanging? Below is a sample code demonstration

```
def force_run():
    os.startfile(.../file.py)
```

Comment: the terminal can only do one thing at a time, unless you start a job in the background. While it's hanging, it's busy with the first command, and it isn't capable of receiving other commands meanwhile, unless the "hanging" command is started in the background.

Comment: Try threading - https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: What kind of "hanging"? The solution to, say, a flow control problem is completely different from a problem where something is blocking waiting for stdin... and are you asking for a Python program that runs in the background and detects this automatically? What, exactly, _are_ you asking for?

Comment: ...the "sample code" you provided doesn't run at all (it's not even valid syntax), and its behavior depends on a separate `file.py` you aren't providing. It's certainly not clear how it relates to the question.

Comment: ...that said, _in general_, if you want to run another process without it being in the foreground, you should be using `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.startfile`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, the hanging is not waiting for input. Its a tkinter program and it hangs the terminal even after getting the output unless the program is closed. I guess all tkinter programs hangs unless the program is closed, right? If not so, is there a command to prevent the tkinter program from hanging?

Comment: Just run it in the background, like `subprocess.Popen` will do -- especially if you set `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`. This isn't called "hanging the terminal", it's called "running in the foreground"; whereas to make it not take control of the terminal, you want to run it in the background. (Or if you're starting your tkinter program from a shell instead of from Python, use `&` to background it)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Your suggestion is a bit confusing, I used ```subprocess.run('start "file.py"', shell=True)``` but it just opens a second terminal. Is this command correct?

Comment: `process_handle = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "file.py"])` is closer to correct; you can then later manipulate `process_handle` to check if the program is still running, shut it down, etc. There are Windows-specific arguments you can pass to `Popen` to control whether extra terminals get invoked, but I live in the UNIX world and don't know/use/care about them. (Also, in the UNIX world, using `shell=True` without a seriously good reason is a sin; that's a little more complicated in Windows, but I still advise avoiding it unless you know _exactly_ why you can't).